# Can't get data attribute value

Tags: php, jquery

Am trying to fetch the data attribute from a dynamically created table using `foreach`.Currently am getting the value od data attribute serviceid of first row only.

This is my php code :

```
<?php foreach ($service_arr as $service) {?>
<tr class="odd gradeX">
<td><button id="delete_btn" type="button"    
data-serviceid="<?=$service->service_id?>"  class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" 
data-target="#ServicesDeleteModal">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
```

I want to fetch the value serviced from the table. Currently if I have three rows generated in `foreach` loop, am getting only the serviceid of first row only (`<tr>`).Why is that?

Jquery Code:

```
$('#delete_btn').click(function(){

var service_id = $(this).attr("data-serviceid");
      console.log(service_id);
});
```

Please help
Thanks

Comment: Who told you to set duplicate ids for the elements..?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have duplicate ids. id selector is only binding the click to first element in matched DOM. Also you should use `.data()` to get set data attribute. and make sure that click event is binded when DOM is ready. something like this:

```
$(function(){$('.btn.btn-default').click(function(){
   var service_id = $(this).data("serviceid");
   console.log(service_id);
});});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the buttons you are generating is that they all have the same id attribute. 
An "id" should be unique !

However, several tags can have the same "class" attribute;

You can replace

```
<td><button id="delete_btn" type="button"  [...]
```

by

```
<td><button class="delete_btn" type="button"  [....]
```

and change your jQuery  selector by that :

```
$('.delete_btn').click(function(){ [...]
```